# Aero Glass mysteriously disappears

Tags: windows, macos, parallels, aero

I am running Windows 7 in a VM (Parallels 5 on Snow Leopard). Every once in a while it decides, all on its own, that I really don't need the Aero Glass UI and turns it off. Rebooting the VM restores it.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of [other people](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=95528) have seen this behavior. A fix will be rolled out in the next Parallels Desktop 5 update as confirmed by a Parallels Team member (see [here](http://forum.parallels.com/showpost.php?s=e32e651e36b61746b7213f5bea25e8e5&p=394687&postcount=60)).